# Build new modern Intra

Tags: intranet, hub-site

In modern Intranet, we use 1 communication Site to be Hub Site and many team site as Department Site associate with Hub Site. Each Department usualy require share data like some list or document Libary with another. What is the most effective way to organize them?

Answer (score 1):

I Prefer not to use a team site in my structure as they can easily go messy and managing it gets hard when there are several of them.
create A top Level Site Collection(from Office 365 admin Panel) 
Then create a Subsite for each Department(You can use the new experience, which is the same as team site) At this stage, Breck, the permission level and create Unique permission for each department.
You can go deep in each department and create subsite for each department If you need.

Now Sharing Part: 
it depends on how you want to handle sharing and the nature of the shared documents(read Only/Co-editing).

For having the same source of trust for every file/ document you can add Links in the Document Library as you need. (this method is the prefered method)

Another way I use MS Flow to copy files between libraries. You need a flow to update different places.
This method makes the permission management easy but it is not good if your files are not read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Ehsan;
I realize the classic way of using subsite organize Permission for departments still useful. But when using subsite, you deny the right for using new apps like Team, Share Outlook, Calendar between the members in each department.
I also realize that if you use the modern way, sharing between other site collections is hard, I am still trying to find a way to organize that. My final goal is that you can organize an Intranet, in this, each Department member has their environment to corporate with another team member also the members of another team site.
I hope Microsoft can soon make a list can use in two or more team site, so the data from different sites can connect and dynamic display to users who need that (Although there may be data from outside their team site)

Answer (score 1):

I would reconsider the purpose of the various sites that have been configured. For example, your root site is a communication site, which is designed publishing content to a wide number of users. Perfect. Team sites are designed for allowing a group of users to collaborate together. Is that what they're being used for in this context, or is their primary purpose to push out info about their dept to the rest of the company?

If both uses are needed, then perhaps two sites are needed. For example, the finance dept could have a publishing site that references the hub site to provide info to other employees about any necessary info re that dept. There could be another site for the finance dept to collaborate on internal content, chat, etc.

For situations where the finance dept needs to share docs with engineering, The solution could simply be another site for that specific collaboration. One thing this solves is the question of ownership. If docs are needed by two departments, there still needs to be an owner of the docs and business processes involved. Having a separate site allows that ownership and those business processes to be clearly defined.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike2500. But in my case, the list or document you want to share between 2 departments,  have input data source from some lists or document from one of these departments, which the only member of these departments can view and edit. The method to connect data from these lists may be Lookup columns, but the Lookup column doesn't allow you to get data from another site. So what you can do in this case?

Comment: So, a single list needs to be used as a source of a lookup column between multiple sites? One option is to look into the use of a "managed metadata" field. This field uses the managed metadata service as its source of choice values instead of a sharepoint list. The same list of values can be used in any list in any site. Or, put everything that needs those lookup lists in the same site. Or, create a script to keep multiple lists across multiple sites in sync. (I don't like the last option at all, though technically it would work).

Comment: Thanks, Mike. But the data I want to pull not only 1 column. It may be 2 or more columns. The "managed metadata column" may good for manage consistently one type of one data in the tenant, but when working with 2 columns or more, it doesn't work.